# Look up and return cell content by cell value

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have to audit a sample of entries on spread sheet A (10% of around 1000 entries) I have used RandBetween to generate a random selection of 100 line numbers on to a new spread sheet (B). I now need to pull the data in column I on sheet A on to spread sheet B for each of those line numbers.

E.g I17, I365 etc.

Is there a formula to do this or do I manually need to search, then copy and paste?

Kind regards Sam

Answer (score 0):

You can use `=INDEX()`formula.

From [MSDN help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb179188%28v=office.12%29.aspx):

> Returns a value or the reference to a value from within a table or
>   range. There are two forms of the INDEX function: the array form and
>   the reference form.

You can try something like this:

```
=INDEX(SheetA!A:B;SheetB!A1;2) 'Search in matrix A:B in sheetA where Row_num = SheetB!A1 and Column_num = 2
```